# How to convert this string into timestamp in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to convert a string into timestamp
I am using the following command for it

```
SELECT To_timestamp ('12-31-2021-23-38-02', 'DD-MM-YYYY-HH24-MI-SS');
```

However it is returning me '2023-07-17 23:38:02' this instead of '2021-31-12 23:38:02'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place of month & day in the input string doesn't match format string.

Use:

```sql
SELECT To_timestamp ('12-31-2021-23-38-02', 'MM-DD-YYYY-HH24-MI-SS');
```

As pointed out in the comments, it's apparent that you're using Postgres prior to version 10.

Since `Postgres 10`, your query throws below error:

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "12-31-2021-23-38-02"
```

[dbfiddle.uk - Postgres 10](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dd3cbd23a3f789f4385e4e7bcc445277)

Comment: Since Postgres 10, the original expression results in "*date/time field value out of range*"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help
I feel so embarrassed right now that I spent half an hour debugging it and was not able to notice that column had date in MM-DD format instead of DD-MM format T_T

Comment: Well, I can only recommend 5 mins break every 25 mins of coding.